# How to fix a broken Sublime 3 word wrap function?

Tags: sublimetext3, settings

I was trying to work on my css and html in two columns but the word wrap function is not working. I have tried making sure word wrap is checked under View. Didn't work.

I went to preferences/settings to override it and make it work. See the picture below. On the right column is the settings and at the bottom you can see where I made word wrap always turn on. Then I made it always set a 100 characters.

On the left is my index.html with a ruler at 100 characters and obviously it didn't work. And, yes, I have closed it and restarted it. Any solutions besides uninstalling and reinstalling? Thank you.

[image: Sublime Screen Shot]

Comment: Visually the ruler in the screenshot doesn't look to be at position 100, just based on counting the characters visible on the first line; is `Verdana` a monospace font? If not, there may be some interplay there.

Comment: You may want to try setting the `wrap_width` to 0, which corresponds to the `Automatic` setting in `View > Word Wrap Column`. That makes Sublime wrap at the edge of the window, which may work better in this case if the idea is to have the text wrap so it's all visible in the left pane.

Comment: The wrap_width was 0 as an automatic setting. After trying the word_wrap: true and it did not work I then tried adding the wrap_width to it. So that has already been tried. I'm going to change the Verdana to a monospace font. I hadn't thought of that one, thank you!

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, the next thing to double check would be that you don't have any syntax specific settings for `HTML` files that might be replacing the setting value without your realizing it.

Comment: IT WORKED! I have Courier New on my computer and it is a monospace font! The word wrap now works perfectly! THANK YOU!!!